# How to store a' | 'delimeted spooled file in hash using perl

Tags: perl, hash

Below is the format which my text file has

```
3PTTN8KS4DE6CT67NJC0|8269076305|22-FEB-13|-79|352
3PTTN8KS4DE6CT67NJC0|8269076305|22-FEB-13|90.83|387
3PY9MEMG0187YWJMBYA1|1114216131|15-FEB-13|-79|352
3PY9MEMG0187YWJMBYA1|1114216131|15-FEB-13|82.95|387
3Q335ZZGMDHZH9GV7TC1|1884476900|20-FEB-13|-79|352
3Q335ZZGMDHZH9GV7TC1|1884476900|20-FEB-13|89.27|387
3QA1Y5QTETP9N984P6W0|685532706|19-FEB-13|-79|352
3QA1Y5QTETP9N984P6W0|685532706|19-FEB-13|90.83|387
3QB8WFBAM94R4WG1Z5R1|1250545621|15-FEB-13|-79|352
3QB8WFBAM94R4WG1Z5R1|1250545621|15-FEB-13|89.27|387
```

Now I would like to read all these values into perl hash. And this file is a huge file and has to be compared with another huge file. For this I would like to store it in perl hash and compare.

Just need the help on how to save this data using perl hash.

Comment: use a csv file parser? `Text::CSV` will do for example. And perhaps an array might me more suited than a hash.

Comment: What part of the data should be the key?

Comment: Define huge? 100 Mb? 1 Gb? 100 Gb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me that you need to split anything, with your question as written. Just put the line into the hash directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# 
# Usage:  
#
# $ compareFiles.pl foo.txt bar.txt
#

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dataRef;

my $sourceFn = $ARGV[0];
open my $sourceFh, "< $sourceFn";
while (<$sourceFh>) {
    chomp;
    my $sourceKey = $_;
    $dataRef->{$sourceKey} = 1;
}
close $sourceFh;
...
```

Now you can compare it by opening up a second file stream and checking if the key exists:

```
...
my $compareFn = $ARGV[1];
open my $compareFh, "< $compareFn";
while (<$compareFh>) {
    chomp;
    my $comparisonKey = $_;
    if (defined $dataRef->{$comparisonKey}) {
        print STDOUT "We found [ $comparisonKey ] in both files!\n";
    }
}
close $compareFh;
```

If you need to adjust the key, so as to compare some subset of values, then use `split("|", $_)` to split the `$sourceKey` and `$comparisonKey` into an indexed list of tokens that you can construct a custom key from, *e.g.*:

```
my $sourceFn = $ARGV[0];
open my $sourceFh, "< $sourceFn";
while (<$sourceFh>) {
    chomp;
    my @sourceElements = split("|", $_);
    my $sourceKey = join("_", ($sourceElements[1], $sourceElements[3], $sourceElements[4]));
    $dataRef->{$sourceKey} = 1;
}
close $sourceFh;
...
```

Etc.

Be sure to construct a comparison key using the same process you used to construct all source keys.

Also, you want to design your key to be unique enough that it serves as a reliable comparison token between two or more inputs.

You basically need to ask yourself what it is that you need to compare between inputs. This isn't clear from your question, as there is a lot of redundant information there that makes use of a hash table a bit tricky.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing some things: (1) Three-arg-`open` is better. Use it. (2) Error handling is a must. Do it. (3) If you test if a hash entry `exists`, do *that*, not ask whether it is `defined`. (4) The first argument to `split` is a regex, not a string! Your pattern `/|/` would have matched everywhere. (5) `join`ing with a different separator was probably a bug. (6) Slices are cool.